# FTP TASK using sql server ssis?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ftp

I have credentials for an FTP Server, e.g.:

```
Server name     port  username  password
ftp.xxx.bb.com  21    abcc      xxxxxx
```

When I attempt to test the connection in SSIS FTP TASK, I get the following error message:

`Connection can not be established. Server name, port number, or credentials may be invalid.`

When I try the connection through the browser or Windows Explorer, I don't have a problem.

Comment: i given dummy ftp. When I try the connection through the browser or Windows Explorer working properly.  But in FTP Task is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark but if your credential are correct you could try turning on or off `Passive mode`

[image: FTP Task]